# Installing Zpanel in Amazon AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, zpanel

I am trying install Zpanel in my Amazon EC2 using Putty in cmd using the follwing steps:

1. Log into your AWS services console and select EC2.
2. You’ll then be directed to the resources window, just click on the blue “Launch Instance” tab.
3. You’ll then be directed to a widow where you should choose an Amazon Machine Image (AMI), select “Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS (PV) –ami-fa9cf1ca (64-bit) / ami-f89cf1c8 (32-bit)“, then click the blue “select” tab.
4. You’ll then be directed to the window where you should select the hardware, select the micro instance “t1.micro”, then click on the grey “Next: Configure Instance Details” not the blue “Review and Launch” tab.
5. You’ll then be directed to the configure instance details window, leave everything as it’s and click on the grey “Add Storage” tab.
6. You’ll then be directed to the window where you should add storage, just leave everything as it’s and click on the grey “Tag Instance” tab.
7. You’ll then be directed to a new window where you should name the instance, just name your instance whatever you like (e.g. Trial, MyAwesomeServer, etc.), then click on the grey “Configure Security Group” tab.
8. You’ll then be directed to the window where you should configure the security group; you’ve to add (HTTP, HTTPS, DNS) from the protocol drop down menu, and make sure that you select “Anywhere” from the source drop down menu. It should look like the screenshot below. Then click on the blue “Review and Launch” tab.
9. You’ll then be directed to the reviewing window, just click on the blue “launch” tab.
10. A new window will appear; first select “create a new key pair” from the drop down menu. Second, name the key pair (e.g. website, MyAwesomeServer, etc.) in key pair name slot. Third, click on the grey “Download key pair” and save it on your local computer (e.g. My Documents, Desktop, etc.), then click on the blue “Launch Instance’ tab.
11. You’ll then be directed to a new window, just click on the blue “view instance” tab. The instance takes between 10~20 minutes to be initialized.
12. Now, till the instance is initialized, open the PuTTYgen you’ve download previously, click on the load button and browse to the “key pair” downloaded in step 10, hint: select “all files” when browsing to find the “key pair”.
13. Click on the “save private key” that appeared after loading the “key pair” and save that key onto your local computer (e.g. desktop), a warning massage will appear just click on “OK”.
14. After the initialization finishes, click on the “Connect” tab in your server console window.
15. New window will popup, just copy the address “ec2-user@54.84.xxx.xxx” as seen below.
16. Now, open PuTTY that you’ve previously downloaded, and paste the address you’ve just copied in the “Host Name (IP Address)” bar as seen below.
17. Now, in the same window but at the side bar you shall find “SSH” click on it then click on the “Auth” in the sub-menu, then browse to the key you’ve created with the PuTTYgen in step “14”, then click open. You’ll then be prompted by a warning message, just click “Yes”.
18. Now you’re on your server console (terminal) and it should look like this:
19. Now, copy and paste  (to paste the commands in the terminal/command prompt window just right click in the terminal) the following commands:
    sudo -i
    cd
    wget https://github.com/zpanel/zpanelx/releases/download/10.1.0/installer-10-1-0-ubuntu-64.sh.x
    chmod +x installer-10-1-0-ubuntu-64.sh.x
    apt-get install curl at
    ./installer-10-1-0-ubuntu-64.sh.x
20. Now, you’ll see a window similar to the screenshot below, and you’ll be asked 5 questions, just type (Y) as an answer to the first question then hit enter for the following 3 questions and finally type (Y) as an answer to the last question; you’ll be prompted by a message telling you that AppArmor has been disabled. Now, exit the terminal (command line window).
21. Go to your instance console window, right click on your instance and then click “reboot”, wait for a couple of minutes and repeat step (17) to re-connect to your server.
22. The terminal window will appear now, just copy and paste the following commands:
    sudo -i
    cd
    ./installer-10-1-0-ubuntu-64.sh.x
23. The same window from step (20) will appear again this time type the following:
    To continue please agree to the GPL license (y/n/q)? Y
    Find your timezone from: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php e.g Europe/London Enter Your Time Zone: Europe/London Just hit Enter.
    Enter the FQDN of the server: zpanel.public IP (e.g. zpanel.54.XXX.XX.XX); if you don’t know your public IP then jump to step (24).
    Enter the Public (external) IP of the server: Just hit Enter
    ZPanel will now install, are you sure (y/n/q)? Y
24. To find your Public IP, go to your AWS console and you shall find it as seen below in the screenshot.
25. At the end of the installation the following window will appear, copy the data inside the hash/window sign, these are your MySQL and ZPanel credentials and then paste them in a notepad and save it on your local computer.
26. Now, type your public IP (from step 24) in your web browser, you should be prompted by the following window (if you can’t then you’ve problem in either step 8 or step 23 “FQDN”).

It is ok upto that and but when i enter the url that is zpanel.54.XXX.XX.XX or 54.XXX.XX.XX  it is not loading it is showing "This webpage is not available" it is saying if it does not come it is probably problem of fqdn,but in fqdn when it asks "Enter the FQDN of the server (example: zpanel.yourdomain.com): ip-172-**-**-**"i entered zpanel.54.XXX.XX.XX.not understanding what is the actual problem

Comment: did you download ubuntu package and try to install on CentOS/Redhat? dpkg is default running on ubuntu.

Comment: i am using Amazon Linux AMI 2014.09.1 (HVM) instance

Comment: that's centos, you need use ubuntu AMI, or download install package for right OS

Comment: i have again done the same steps now using ubuntu but still it is saying when i go to my public ip that "This webpage is not available", can you give some step instruction

Comment: If it is new error. you need update in your question with detail.

Comment: is there any latest tutorial link for doing it ?